# I want to do the verification of a field in which upload image in Yii2

Tags: php, database, yii2

#### My View form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'img')->fileInput() ?>
```

#### Model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['nome', 'proprietario', 'descricao', 'contacto', 'website', 'cp4', 'cp3', 'localidade', 'morada', 'estado'], 'required', 'message' => 'Por favor preencha os campos'],
        [['contacto', 'cp4', 'cp3'], 'integer', 'message' => 'Este campo só aceita números.'],
        [['estado'], 'string'],
        [['nome', 'proprietario', 'localidade', 'morada'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
        [['descricao'], 'string', 'max' => 200],

        //Theres the img that corresponds to fileInput field
        [['website', 'img'], 'string', 'max' => 255],

    ];
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function actionCreateRegistoPropriedade()
{
    $model = new Hotel();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img');

        $model->save();

        $hotelid = $model->id;
        $image_name = 'hotel_' . $hotelid . '.' . $image->getExtension();
        $image->saveAs("../web/assets/hoteis/" . $image_name);
        $model->img = $image_name;

        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['create-registo-propriedade']);
    }
    return $this->render('createRegistoPropriedade', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

When I don't choose any images, it gives me an error that is the following "Call to a member function getExtension() on null"

That getExtension() corresponds to my "actionCreateRegistoPropriedade()" function on controller

Comment: Your `file` property must be file in your rules. Check it here - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload or use this for saving file name, but create new public property for your file input

Comment: I've already researched it. But I want to save only the file name in the string database. And not in file format

Comment: If you've not uploaded a file then `UploadedFile::getInstance()` returns `null`. You need to check `$image`, e.g. `if ($image) {  }`

Answer (score 0):

In you model you have to create new property for file input:

```
public $img_file;
```

Then in your _form use this property:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'img_file')->fileInput() ?>
```

In your controller change you code like that:

```
public function actionCreateRegistoPropriedade()
{
    $model = new Hotel();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img_file'); //change it here

        $model->save();

        $hotelid = $model->id;
        $image_name = 'hotel_' . $hotelid . '.' . $image->getExtension();
        if($image->saveAs("../web/assets/hoteis/" . $image_name)){
            $model->img = $image_name;
            $model->save();
        }

        return $this->redirect(['create-registo-propriedade']);
    }
    return $this->render('createRegistoPropriedade', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

PS. Check article in my comment for additional validations